# killing or stopping the python script in lettuce

Tags: python, linux, automation, debian, lettuce

I have a python script it sends data permanently and after seeing its output  I want to stop or kill the python script .in lettuce I couldn't manage to kill python script.Any idea for this?
I tried that:

```
os.system('pgrep -f sample.py')
    time.sleep(3.0)
 os.system('pkill -9 -f sample.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try subprocess, its much more clean and elegant the command output can be read via the p.communicate() after executing the command.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-f', 'sample.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
pid = p
time.sleep(3.0)
os.kill(pid=pid, sig=9)
```

Comment: didnt work :( I stopped with Ctrl+C manually ..after then it tries to read subprocess commands.